# Fiber product of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, category-theory

Let $f: G \longrightarrow K$, $g: H \longrightarrow K$ be group homomorphisms. For the fiber product $G \times_K H$ to exist, is it necessary to require that $f$ and $g$ be surjective?

I can't see why this would be important, but all sources I could find on the internet (e.g. the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_groups#Fiber_products)) have this requirement.

Comment: The wikipedia article should be changed immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need the maps to be surjective. The [category of groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_groups) is complete (all limits exist) so you don't need any requirements on the morphisms here. You can easily just construct the fibre product by taking the product of the sources $G\times H$ and then the equalizer of $f \circ \pi_1$ and $g \circ \pi_2$.

Comment: In other words, take the subgroup of $G \times H$ given by $\{(x,y) : f(x)=g(y)\}$. The same construction works in all algebraic categories (replace "subgroup" by "substructure") and also in the category of topological spaces for instance (replace "subgroup" by "subspace"). These are special cases of the general construction of fiber products via products and equalizers which you have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

If we don't have the surjectivity we will loose Goursat's lemma. Since a fiber product will no longer be always a subdirect product.

Comment: What is the importance of Goursat's lemma?

Comment: Probably [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goursat%27s_lemma) will help.